# Reflect on self vs self-reflect

Tags: meaning, difference

Does *to reflect on self* has the same meaning as *to self-reflect*, or can they ever be used interchangeably ?

Comment: Neither feels common to me.  I've heard "to reflect on ones self" before and the concept of self reflection, but neither of your terms feels right.  Perhaps with a context sentence?

Comment: Simply "reflect" is the more common usage. E.G. "I need some time to reflect." Reflexiveness is implied until you add "on x".
You may also be looking for "introspect"/"introspection".

Comment: "To reflect on one's self" is a common phrase in philosophy.